# Bootstrap 3.1 popover with CSS column-count cutting off in ipad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari, popover, column-count

http://www.bootply.com/117079

Is there something wrong with the CSS I'm using?  Viewed on the iPad, Safari cuts off characters in each column.  It works fine on Chrome when I look at it on my desktop.

Other things I've tried:

- Add a minimum width for each item (wrapped with spans)
- Add prefix-column-width (this removes the columns entirely but expands the width - http://www.bootply.com/117081)